# IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Receiving this error from console:

```
*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:  
    IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
 [/WEB-    INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is   
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource        
[/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]*
```

That's the error I receive from:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>fj21-tarefas</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>


        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

[image: projects folder]

I doing

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

to change the default context from springmvc, but it is not working. Already took some advice here to write a servlet-name tag to the file name-context.xml convention, same error.

Comment: I think you should add file: before value. file:/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml

Comment: @HarshalKhachane It's gives me the previous error with this one now: 
_GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [file:/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \WEB-INF\spring-context.xml _

Answer (score 1):

You should try changing the servlet name. Expected Spring web-context metadata XML file name should `servletname-servlet.xml`, this was expected filename till Spring 4, not sure if it is changed in spring 5.
. As your servlet name is `springmvc`, filename should be `springmvc-servlet.xml`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app-name/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: The error keeps on.... `ERROR ContextLoader:319 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]`

Comment: No just spring-context.xml and web.xml.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the codebase? May be on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Make your web.xml look like this, taken straight from the Spring documentation:

```
<web-app>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: param-value is null.

Comment: Give it a try :)